# Getting viewport bounding box for United Kingdoms

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bounding-box, google-geocoding-api

I'm using Google Maps Geocode to get the recommended viewport bounding box when displaying countries on a map.

This works really well for almost all countries, and it used to work well for the UK as well.

In the geocoding response, there's the `geometry` property that includes a `viewport` property. For the UK this viewport used to include the Great Britain and Northern Ireland, recently, however, it also includes the Akrotiri and Dhekelia territory which is on the island of Cyprus. Fitting the map bounds to this area will display most of Europe.

The solution I've found thus far is to fit the map bounds to the bounding box of Great Britain, this, however, excludes the Northern Ireland which I also want to have visible.

How can I get a bounding box that contains both the Great Britain island Northern Ireland?

I know I can hard code it, it's unlikely to change (unless Scotland decides to go independent). But I would like to find another solution.

Comment: Union the viewports for Great Britain and Northern Ireland

Answer (score 0):

The best i could get is this https://jsfiddle.net/7tc0rv2p/1/ (will need to add API key)

You can use:

```
resultsMap.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
resultsMap.panToBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
```

And instead of GB or UK, use England and i found apart from a very minute amount of Scotland it shown the entire part you need, but that should be able to be adjusted if the top of Scotland is absolutely needed.